# Kernel of a homomorphism map

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\pi : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $(x,y)\mapsto x + y$. Describe the kernel and fibers of $\pi$ geometrically.

**My attempt:** Let $x,y,z$ and $w$ be in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\pi((x,y)+(y,z))=\pi(x,y)+\pi(z,y)$, it is a homomorphism. Determining the kernel of $\pi$, I therefore would use $\ker\pi=\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}\mid x+y=0_{\mathbb{R}}\rbrace$, where $0$ is an identity in a group $\mathbb{R}$ under addition. Thus we have $\ker\pi=\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}\mid y=-x\rbrace$. It is a line in $\mathbb{R}$. The fibers of $\pi$ in $k\in \mathbb{R}$ is $\pi^{-1}(\lbrace k\rbrace)=\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}\mid x+y=k\rbrace$, which is a line in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I'd like to know if my attempt is correct. If not, please show me the better way.

Comment: Yours looks perfectly fine - it might be a more complete answer if you describe the direction of the lines (e.g. "with slope $-1$" or "parallel the line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,-1)$" or at least "all fibers are parallel").

Comment: @Meelo, You are completely right. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel of $\pi$ is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ so that $x+y=0$ , so $y=-x$. Hence it is a line with slope $-1$ that passes through the origin.

What is the fiber of $r$? It is the set of pairs of $(x,y)$ so that $x+y=r$ , so $y=-x+r$. hence it is a line with slope $-1$ and $y$-intercept $r$.

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot to add the description more properly. Looks like my attempt is fine until then.